# setTimout() ajax request doesn't work successfully

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the code below the line

```
setTimeout(Comet_IrsaliyeBelgeDurum(sGuid, belgeOid), 10000)
```

doesn't make the Comet Function wait 10 seconds.
The Function is running continuously.

The setTimeout parameter seems to have no effect.

How do I make the code wait 10 seconds?

```
function Comet_IrsaliyeBelgeDurum(sGuid, belgeOid) {

            var params = {
                sGuid: sGuid,
                belgeOid: belgeOid
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: params,
                url: '/BetonHareketler/H_BetonIrsaliyeBelgeDurum',
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data.isSuccess) {

                        if (data.entity == 2 || data.entity == 4) {
                            toastr.success(data.SuccessfullMessage, 'İşlemi Başarılı');
                        }
                        else {
                            toastr.info(data.SuccessfullMessage, 'İşlemi Başarılı');
                            setTimeout(Comet_IrsaliyeBelgeDurum(sGuid, belgeOid), 10000);
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        toastr.error(data.SuccessfullMessage, 'İşlemi Başarısız');
                    }

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("Bağlantı Hatası. Sayfaya Yenileyin");
                    window.location.replace(window.location.href);
                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setTimeout` accepts a function which it calls after the delay has passed.

```
setTimeout(Comet_IrsaliyeBelgeDurum(sGuid, belgeOid), 10000);
           ^---------------------------------------^
                      this got evaluated
```

What your code is doing is call `Comet_IrsaliyeBelgeDurum` and used its return value, whatever it is, as the "function" for `setTimeout`.

What you need to do is just wrap this in another function like so:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  Comet_IrsaliyeBelgeDurum(sGuid, belgeOid)
}, 10000);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your sugesstion. now I'm aware of the problem

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the way you call setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(Comet_IrsaliyeBelgeDurum(sGuid, belgeOid), 10000);
```

Javascript is a pass-by-value language.  This means that all the paramaters you pass are evaluated before they are given to the function.

This means that you are passing the values, `Comet_IrsaliyeBelgeDurum(sGuid, belgeOid)` and `10000` to setTimeout.  This then calls the function `Comet_IrsaliyeBelgeDurum`.

What you want to do is pass a function (not the result of a function) to `setTimeout`.  See Joseph's answer for an example.